# Silverlight 4 lookless control. Bind to another element in the same control

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have created a lookless control using silverlight 4. This control contains a textbox which the user will type data into and a button that increases the size of the textbox by increasing the MinHeight of the control by 10 each time it is pressed (I have set the textbox to stretch so it grows with the control).

This bit works fine but I now want to extend the controls functionality by adding another textbox that will display the current MinHeight of the control which I dont seem to be able to do. I have been trying

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MinHeight, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Im not sure why but this always shows as 0

**Update**

In my attempts to resolve I tried chaging the name of the source textbox to PART_sourceData and just to see if the binding was correct I set the path to the text property. This appears to bring through the text of the sourcedata as I would expect

```
Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=PART_sourceData, Path=Text}"
```

My next step was to change the path to Height

```
Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=PART_sourceData, Path=Height}"
```

But this returns NaN. Therefore I tried MinHeight

```
Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=PART_sourceData, Path=MinHeight}"
```

This always returns 0 even though the code behind has a valid number. Whats going wrong? Becuase the text comes through properly I beleive the binding to be correct but whats wrong with getting the height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have a solution. Not the best but it works!

I have had to create a new dependancy property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EditorHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EditorHeight", typeof(string), typeof(EditorControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string EditorHeight
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EditorHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditorHeightProperty, value); }
    }
```

Then I bind the text to this property using

```
Text="{TemplateBinding EditorHeight}"
```

Answer (score 0):

By binding to `RelativeSource Self` you are looking at that controls MinHeight.  You will need to name your original TextBox with the `x:Name` attribute, then use `ElementName` binding.

Comment: Sorry Im a newbie so not 100% sure what you mean. I have changed the name of my original textbox from Name="sourceData" to x:Name="sourceData" and the binding to Text="{Binding ElementName=sourceData, Path=MinHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"> is this what you meant?

Comment: That looks right to me.  Whenever I'm not sure about the syntax for my bindings, I always do it through the designer.